# CORS: Is the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header mandatory for subsequent calls to the OPTIONS request?

Tags: http, request, cors

I have an application that require credentials. For the preflight requests, I am returning `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to `true` only in `OPTIONS` requests. I assumed that this header would not be necessary in subsequent requests but it is failing.

Is this behaviour expected or should I perform modifications?

The MDN website mentions the following but it is not entirely clear to me:

> When used as part of a response to a preflight request, this indicates whether or not the actual request can be made using credentials. Note that simple GET requests are not preflighted. So, if a request is made for a resource with credentials, and if this header is not returned with the resource, the response is ignored by the browser and not returned to the web content.

([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials))

The fetch standard includes this note for `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header but it's not clear to me either.

> For a CORS-preflight request, request’s credentials mode is always "same-origin", i.e., it excludes credentials, but for any subsequent CORS requests it might not be. Support therefore needs to be indicated as part of the HTTP response to the CORS-preflight request as well.

([source](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-access-control-allow-credentials))

I am returning `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to `true` only in `OPTIONS` requests assuming that in the following calls this header would not be needed.
The `OPTIONS` request is successful but the browser blocks the subsequent `POST` request (which does not include `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to `true`) with the next message:

[image: CORS Error]

Answer (score 1):

You want to make a credentialed CORS request (that is, `fetch(..., {credentials: "include"})`) that requires a preflight (for example, because it is a POST request with `Content-Type: application/json`).

Without the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` header in the preflight response, the browser would not make the credentialed request in the first place.

Since you set that header in the preflight response, the browser makes the credentialed request (so that the effect happens on the server). But then the response lacks a header `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`, therefore the browser refuses to make the response accessible to Javascript. This is the same behavior as if you made a simple CORS GET request (which does not require a preflight) but the response lacks an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

So you really need this header in both responses.