# CORS: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.", but pre-flight data shows that it is

Tags: flutter, cors, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I've been trying to figure this out for over a day and I'm out of ideas.
I've built a website using Flutter web, with the backend hosted in the Oracle cloud and accessed via a gateway function (cloud hosted).The site itself is hosted on Firebase.

I'm getting a 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.' error in the console, but looking at the pre-flight data in the network tab, it would appear that it is:
[image]

Another weird thing is that I've asked 3 of my colleagues to run my site, and 1 other had the same issue, but the other 2 have been completely fine. I'm completely out of idea, has anyone run into this? May be of no importance, but I've had no issues running this on localhost.

Edit: Here is the code as requested:

```dart
Future conductSearch(String searchId, String searchType) async {
    String token = GetIt.instance.get<User>().idToken.toString();
    bool loggedIn = GetIt.instance.get<User>().loggedIn;
    print(token);
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'x-om-sso': token,
      'x-om-auth': 'e35kk!7iG&9VuW!OeZ6\$eqSYeVo',
      'content-type': 'application/json',
    };

    if (loggedIn) {
      final url = Uri.https(
          'testing.testing.com',
          '/$searchId/$searchType');
      print("url:  $url");
      try {
        print("inside the try block");
        var response = await http.get(url, headers: headers);
        print(response);
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          return jsonDecode(response.body);
        } else {}
      } catch (e) {
        throw Exception(e);
      }
    } else {
      // todo add full error handling here
      throw Error();
    }
  }
```

All the API requests go through this one function, just taking a different searchId and searchType. I've changed the url here for security, but I can confirm that the URL works fine via localhost and when requested from  postman, returning the data I need.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you share the code that is going wrong exactly ?

Comment: @JhonSabowsla apologies, just added

Comment: The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is in the preflight response, but is it also in the response to the subsequent ("real") request? Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/75004298/16462950.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, String> headers = {
  'x-om-sso': token,
  'x-om-auth': 'e35kk!7iG&9VuW!OeZ6\$eqSYeVo',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
};
```

if these are your headers, you are missing the Allow-Origin header, try like this

```
Map<String, String> headers = {
  'Accept': '*/*',
  'x-om-sso': token,
  'x-om-auth': 'e35kk!7iG&9VuW!OeZ6\$eqSYeVo',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

After far too long it turns out the issue was nothing to-do with Dart/Flutter/ http per se, but bit defender being a bit over zealous. Tweaked the gateway slightly to get around it and all is working fine for everyone –